# Target WSGI script cannot be loaded as Python module + ImportError: No module named

Tags: python, apache, flask, apache2, mod-wsgi

I am having a an error while using mod_wsgi to deploy my flask app. This is the error log:

```
[Sat Feb 10 01:58:24.785611 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 17184:tid 140591748056832] [remote 41.36.31.164:45065] mod_wsgi (pid=17184): Target WSGI script '/var/www/itemcatalog/itemcatalog.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sat Feb 10 01:58:24.785635 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 17184:tid 140591748056832] [remote 41.36.31.164:45065] mod_wsgi (pid=17184): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/itemcatalog/itemcatalog.wsgi'.
[Sat Feb 10 01:58:24.785649 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 17184:tid 140591748056832] [remote 41.36.31.164:45065] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Feb 10 01:58:24.785664 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 17184:tid 140591748056832] [remote 41.36.31.164:45065]   File "/var/www/itemcatalog/itemcatalog.wsgi", line 6, in <module>
[Sat Feb 10 01:58:24.785710 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 17184:tid 140591748056832] [remote 41.36.31.164:45065]     from itemcatalog import app as application
[Sat Feb 10 01:58:24.785729 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 17184:tid 140591748056832] [remote 41.36.31.164:45065] ImportError: No module named itemcatalog
```

I have an **init**.py file inside itemcatalog directory, I did some search and found that maybe that python doesn't identify my itemcatalog as a package, what is the reason for this?

Python was installed globally but then I also tried to also install it inside a virtual environment.

This is the code for the virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName 18.194.244.229
            ServerAdmin admin@18.194.244.229
            WSGIDaemonProcess itemcatalog python-path=/var/www/itemcatalog:/var/www/itemcatalog/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
            WSGIProcessGroup itemcatalog
            WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/itemcatalog/itemcatalog.wsgi

            <Directory /var/www/itemcatalog/>
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
             </Directory>

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            LogLevel warn
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is the file structure inside `/var/www/itemcatalog/`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess itemcatalog python-path=/var/www/itemcatalog:/var/www/itemcatalog/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

use:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess itemcatalog python-path=/var/www \
  python-home=/var/www/itemcatalog/venv
```

The Python path must be the parent directory of the package, not the package directory itself.

Instead of using `python-path` to setup virtual environment, use `python-home` as explained in official documentation:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html